# WASSession E SessionContextMBeanAdapter findAttCausingNotSerializableException

Tags: multithreading, exception, serialization, runtime, websphere

We are getting below mentioned exception in our sysout.log file.
Please provide your help on how we can solve this.

Is there any setting which we can make into the Websphere Application Server?

> 000000a3 WASSession    E SessionContextMBeanAdapter
>   findAttCausingNotSerializableException Miscellaneous data: Attribute
>   "EXCELEXPORTERREGISTERID" is declared to be serializable but is found
>   to generate exception "java.io.NotSerializableException" with message
>   "com.ubs.fsl.idama.action.codification.CodificationsHandler$1".  Fix
>   the application so that the attribute "EXCELEXPORTERREGISTERID" is
>   correctly serializable at runtime.

We have implemented serialization where ever required in our java code.
After that it is giving the below exception.

> 00000078 WASSession    E SessionContextMBeanAdapter
>   findAttCausingNotSerializableException Miscellaneous data: Attribute
>   "com.ubs.fsl.ca.ia.CAReceptionRoomIA" is declared to be serializable
>   but is found to generate exception "java.io.NotSerializableException"
>   with message "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest".  Fix the
>   application so that the attribute
>   "com.ubs.fsl.ca.ia.CAReceptionRoomIA" is correctly serializable at
>   runtime.

Note : The above exceptions started when we migrated from WAS 7.0.0.31 to WAS 9.0.0.5.

Comment: Verify your Java version.  If memory serves WAS 9 is Java EE V7 and WAS 7 is Java EE V6.  New Java implies modifications.  The error message is pretty clear, some attributes are not serializable as written.

Comment: we have also migrated our java version from JAVA 6 to JAVA 8.

Comment: Looks like your class `CAReceptionRoomIA` is directly or indirectly holding `ServletRequest` object, which is clearly not serializable. You have to mark it as transient in that class.